# Manifest merger failed error when try to upgrade to 26.0.0-alpha1

Tags: android, android-manifest, manifest-merging

I have these dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:25.3.1'
    compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.8.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.4.3'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.5'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.1.1'
    compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.github.ksoichiro:android-observablescrollview:1.6.0'
    compile 'net.i2p.android.ext:floatingactionbutton:1.10.0'
    compile 'com.lsjwzh:materialloadingprogressbar:0.5.8-RELEASE'
    compile 'org.sufficientlysecure:html-textview:1.3'
    compile 'com.github.mrengineer13:snackbar:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.vajro:MaterialDesignLibrary:1.6'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.github.AndroidDeveloperLB:MaterialPreferenceLibrary:5'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
    compile 'com.nbsp:library:1.2'
    compile 'io.ticofab.androidgpxparser:parser:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.annimon:stream:1.1.6'
    compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:weather-icons-typeface:2.0.10.2@aar'
    compile 'uk.co.samuelwall:material-tap-target-prompt:1.10.0'
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.2'
    compile 'it.sephiroth.android.library.bottomnavigation:bottom-navigation:2.0.1-rc1'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:google-material-typeface:3.0.1.0.original@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:material-design-iconic-typeface:2.2.0.2@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:iconics-core:2.8.6@aar'
    compile 'com.github.florent37:materialtextfield:1.0.7'
    compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:cardslib-core:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:cardslib-cards:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:cardslib-recyclerview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.github.jkwiecien:EasyImage:1.3.1'
    compile 'com.chauthai.swipereveallayout:swipe-reveal-layout:1.4.0'
    compile 'com.github.jd-alexander:library:1.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
}
```

for `compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'`, I get the following error message:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
>   Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(25.3.1) from [com.android.support:support-v13:25.3.1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-31 
>       is also present at [com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-38 value=(26.0.0-alpha1).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:25:5-27:34 to override.

Any suggestion how to fix the error?

Comment: Have you tried Clean project and Rebuild project ?

Comment: try, clean and rebuild

Comment: post entire gradle

Comment: All is around this library: implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.4.3'. I have updated to 0.9.4.7 but now is a conflict between 26.1.0 and 26.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification

I think the problem is with the com.afollestad.material-dialogs library and you have to force the library version as described here

[Support Lib Update 25.3.1 Material Dialog](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs/issues/1340)

Comment: I solved . All was around afollestad library. I updated to implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.5.0' and SDK to 27. Thanks for support.